# Productivity improvements using Automation Tools

Tags: automation, sdlc

Does any one have figures giving productivity improvements using automation tools in the SDLC?

Comment: Define "productivity improvement". Define "Automation tool".

Answer (score 0):

Failure to take advantage of the latest technology to automate processes that require a certain monotony puts the company behind quickly. In the same way, there are some benefits such as: improved precision: Unlike employees, intelligent automation processes do not get tired or make mistakes when they are tired. Increased productivity: In general, intelligent automation cuts process times in half or more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm in a team applying generative programming techniques using Patterns, primarily in Eclipse. We've done about 50 projects in the last 2 years and achieved typically 4-10X productivity improvements over existing development tools - and in some cases 100x. I'm sold on it!